# SQL grouping not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I am using MS SQL Server 2012

I have a query that uses a subquery to create a column that shows summed percent of assets. However I need that summed column to group by portfoliobasecode as shown below.

I have tried group by and Partition without success. With Group by the result is the portfolio codes correctly group but the summedpct is still the total of all portfolios and not subtotaling as I want.

[image: CashPCT]

With Partition I get the following error. I can use Top 1 but this does not give the desired result.

ERROR

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

[image: error]

Using TOP 1

[image: top1]

It may be I am placing group by or partition over in the wrong place in the query. I need a way to correctly group the column summedpct.

Here is the query:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/cashpercent.sql

Here is the result set and desired result.

[image: CashPCT]

The problem with the actual result is it is taking the sum total of all PercentAssets and placing them in summedpct.

The result I want is these percent of assets grouped by portfoliobasecode. Note in the desired result set the summedpct of chambetr is 2.66 which is -457.50+460.18

Comment: Please revise your question and show the **complete** queries as a "code" block (not an image).  Most folks don't like the "dropbox" approach.  That will make the question much easier to answer.

Comment: Looks like you've answered it but in the future I will paste the query not a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an "inline" query because it returns one row for each partition.  So, you need a "join" I think.  Perhaps this will work:

```
 USE APXFIRM
--1. Establish the APX user session
DECLARE @SessionGUID nvarchar(70)
EXEC APXuser.pSessionInfoSetGuid @SessionGuid

--2. Execute the query against the Appraisal accounting function
DECLARE @ReportData varbinary(max)
EXEC APXUser.pAppraisal

-- Required Parameters. There may be other Optional Parameters.
@ReportData = @ReportData out,
@Portfolios = '@Test_Group',
@Date = '10/02/2013'

--3. Select the columns

SELECT
--Appraisal columns
a.MarketValue,
a.PercentAssets,
--Security Columns
s.SecuritySymbol,
s.SecurityTypeCode,

-- Portfolio Base columns
b.PortfolioBaseCode,
b.ReportHeading1,
bb.summedpct

--4. Join the Appraisal to additional views
FROM APXUser.fAppraisal (@ReportData) a
LEFT JOIN APXUser.vPortfolioBaseSettingEx b
ON b.PortfolioBaseID = a.PortfolioBaseID
LEFT JOIN APXUser.vSecurityVariant s
ON s.SecurityID = a.SecurityID


LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT PortfolioBaseCode
       , SUM(PercentAssets) as summedpct
   FROM APXUser.fAppraisal (@ReportData) aa
   LEFT JOIN APXUser.vPortfolioBaseSettingEx b
ON b.PortfolioBaseID = aa.PortfolioBaseID
LEFT JOIN APXUser.vSecurityVariant s
ON s.SecurityID = aa.SecurityID

   WHERE s.SecTypeCode LIKe 'ca%'

   AND s.SecTypeCode = aa.SecTypeCode
   AND s.IsShort = aa.IsShortPosition
   GROUP BY PortfolioBaseCode, SecurityTypeCode
   ) bb
on b.PortfolioBaseCode = bb.PortfolioBaseCode
WHERE s.SecTypeCode LIKe 'ca%'
AND s.SecTypeCode = a.SecTypeCode
AND s.IsShort = a.IsShortPosition
And summedpct >= @summedpct
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. I am getting various errors that the columns cannot be bound in the JOIN you added. The multi-part identifier "s.SecTypeCode" could not be bound. Invalid column name 'PortfolioBaseCode'. etc... Do they need to be prefixed with aliases?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.  It's hard to tell without seeing the complete definition of each table.  You may need to add JOIN components to the derived table itself.

Comment: Glad you got it working; I figured this would get you there eventually.  Feel free to edit my answer to show the changes you made to get it to work.  I'm guessing you changed the derived table definition by adding additional JOINs.  Updating the answer might help future readers.

Comment: Okay I edited your example which was very close to the result. I just needed to add the following    LEFT JOIN APXUser.vPortfolioBaseSettingEx b
ON b.PortfolioBaseID = aa.PortfolioBaseID
LEFT JOIN APXUser.vSecurityVariant s
ON s.SecurityID = aa.SecurityID

Comment: also added the user defined parameter And summedpct >= @summedpct